# How to decide which endpoint type to use, Spring Integration

Tags: jms, spring-integration, rmi, amqp

I've tried SI with TCP, works great. I am trying to decide which type of endpoint I should use for a simple scenario.

Two Java processes running within the same machine, which needs to talks to each other.

There are so many options, for example: AMQP, JMS, MQTT, TCP, RMI.
I am sure TCP works too, async and reliable, but it needs network, it is better to have an option which do not need network, and work cross platform when I port these processes to run on different OS, for example from Linux to Windows.

To simplify my question, which ones of these works without network (NIC and IPs)?
If I want to run these two processes on different machine and connect through network, which one is the best and why?
Does RMI version still support async and reliable connection?

Answer (score 0):

Another factor is whether or not the two endpoints are in the same java VM.

What is "best" is often greatly influenced by what you're familiar with and have easily available. Also, what do you need for replies? How about guaranteed delivery?

With Camel it's pretty easy to pick one and go; if you need to change later it's not very hard.

seda and VM are two components to look into - they're easy to use, no setup needed - but if your application doesn't fit into the restrictions you need something else.

I gravitate toward AMQP, so I tend to go with that, AMQP and JMS, across nodes.

Comment: Steve, does AMQP or JMS run over TCP/UDP?

Comment: AMQP runs over TCP. JMS is an API, not a wire protocol. JMS can use AMQP. If you are writing in Java then JMS can be a good way to use AMQP.